# Running Jetty 7 as service on Debian/Ubuntu…

Tags: ubuntu, service, jetty, debian

I'm having trouble running jetty 7 as a service in Ubuntu.

Jetty 6 was running fine, but I had to upgrade. The problem I have is that Jetty starts up two java processes and after stopping either from the script I have copied to /etc/init.d or directly from jettys bin folder, ONE process still remains:

```
~/jetty/bin$ sudo ./jetty.sh start
Starting Jetty: OK
~/jetty/bin$ ps ax | grep jetty
28888 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/java -Djetty.home=/usr/share/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -jar /usr/share/jetty/start.jar --pre=etc/jetty-logging.xml --daemon
28904 ?        Sl     0:05 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/bin/java -Xmx2000m -Xmn512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Djetty.home=/usr/share/jetty -cp /usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-xml-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-http-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-continuation-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-server-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-security-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-servlet-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-webapp-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-deploy-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-servlets-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-jmx-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/com.sun.el_1.0.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/ecj-3.6.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.el_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/jetty-jsp-2.1-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.1.0.v201007080150.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/resources:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-websocket-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-util-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-io-7.3.0.v20110203.jar org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration /tmp/start6429233784810245794.properties /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-logging.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-deploy.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-webapps.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-contexts.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-testrealm.xml
28938 pts/1    R+     0:00 grep jetty
~/jetty/bin$ sudo ./jetty.sh stop
Stopping Jetty: OK
~/jetty/bin$ ps ax | grep jetty
28904 ?        Sl     0:31 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/bin/java -Xmx2000m -Xmn512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Djetty.home=/usr/share/jetty -cp /usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-xml-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-http-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-continuation-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-server-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-security-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-servlet-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-webapp-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-deploy-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-servlets-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-jmx-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/com.sun.el_1.0.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/ecj-3.6.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.el_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/jetty-jsp-2.1-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.1.0.v201007080150.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar:/usr/share/jetty/resources:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-websocket-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-util-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/usr/share/jetty/lib/jetty-io-7.3.0.v20110203.jar org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration /tmp/start6429233784810245794.properties /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-logging.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-deploy.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-webapps.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-contexts.xml /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty-testrealm.xml
~/jetty/bin$ sudo kill 28904
~/jetty/bin$ ps ax | grep jetty
29017 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep jetty
```

It's really annoying having to manually kill it all the time. Anyone know why?

More info:
It seems like the "wrong" process is stored in the pid-file and then stopped by the stop-script: If I manually kill the other one instead, both stops.

Comment: Did your ever solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I'm also having this problem and can't figure out how to solve it. If you found a solution, would be good to share!

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried "service jetty stop" / "service jetty start" ?

Comment: Yes, after running stop and start I end with 3 processes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use init-scripts.

You can compose them from scratch or you install [.deb packages with scripts already included:](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debian+Packages)  
([Or here](http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/deb/)).

Don't worry about the Debian notices. It fits Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I did that, but then tried the scripts directly to isolate before asking my question. The scripts under init.d where just using the those scripts anyway.

Answer (score -2):

nano /etc/default/jetty

cambiar:

NO_START=1

por:

NO_START=0

luego ejecuta:

service jetty start

Comment: Could you please post your answer in English with a properly formatted code?